# how to add array object values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi all i am using `javascript` working with array i have a set of data to do add array values object here i attached my code help how to solve this

data

```
var data=[{one:1,two:2},{one:1,two:2},{one:1,two:2},{one:1,two:2}]
```

expected output

```
var sumdata=[{one:4,two:8}]
```

NOTE:one two column name is not static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var resObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   for (var item in data[i]) {
      if (!resObj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
         resObj[item] = data[i][item];
      } else {
         resObj[item] += data[i][item];
      }
    }
 }
 var sumdata = [resObj];
```

Comment: I think this is best answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object as result and iterate the keys of the object and sum the values.

```js
var data = [{ one: 1, two: 2 }, { one: 1, two: 2 }, { one: 1, two: 2 }, { one: 1, two: 2 }],
    result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {    // iterate array
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) { // iterate the keys of the object
            r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + o[k];        // check if a property exists or take zero
        });                                   // and add the actual value
        return r;                             // return the object
    }, Object.create(null));                  // start with an empty object without
                                              // some prototypes 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you'r technically modifying the same object here !

Comment: i would prob replace Object.create(null) with {}, but that's just me :) Nice answer !

Comment: it would not work, if you have `toString` as own property, an you like to count the values of it.